# What is the different between echo and return in laravel route anonymous function. I saw the same output when return a page and echo a page

Tags: laravel

```
route::get('about/', function(){
    return  view('about');
});

route::get('contact', function(){
    echo view('contact');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo` for show outputs content to the console or the web browser.

For example, 
`Route::get('test', function () {

```
$users = User::paginate(1);

echo response()->json(['users' => $users]);
```

});

Result,

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type:
>   application/json Date: Sun, 10 Jun 2018 08:06:47 GMT
>   {"users":{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"name":"di26ek","email":"di26ek@test.com","created_at":"2018-06-06
>   06:15:35","updated_at":"2018-06-06
>   06:15:35"}],"first_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?page=1","from":1,"last_page":90,"last_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?page=90","next_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?page=2","path":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test","per_page":1,"prev_page_url":null,"to":1,"total":90}}
>   `

`return` for return a value or result,

For example,

```
Route::get('test', function () {

    $users = User::paginate(1);

    return response()->json(['users' => $users]);
});
```

Result,

> {"users":{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"name":"di26ek","email":"di26ek@test.com","created_at":"2018-06-06
>   06:15:35","updated_at":"2018-06-06
>   06:15:35"}],"first_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?page=1","from":1,"last_page":90,"last_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?page=90","next_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?page=2","path":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/test","per_page":1,"prev_page_url":null,"to":1,"total":90}}

Comment: You have written one page essay for just 1 marks question.

Comment: I just want to help.